# Nested ajax async execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have three nested ajax async requests that i use to fetch data to a javascript dataTable.
This is pseudo code for it, the first two calls are to a web-API and the third to a controller in my MVC project getting data from localDB.

It should take around 1min to get the data, the progressbar updates correctly but all the rows are added to my dataTable when all data is completed. There must be something wrong with my 3rd request to controller.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: 'ListDevices'
dataType: 'json',
async: true,
success: function () {

     $.ajax({
     type: 'GET',
     url: 'GetLocationsForDevice'
     dataType: 'json',
     async: true,
     success: function () {

          $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'GetDetailsForLocationFromDB'
          dataType: 'json',
          async: true,
          success: function () {
                   //Add a new row to dataTable 
          }
          //Update progressbar   
     }
}
```

Everything in the 3rd request seems to get qued up and executed at the end. Any ideas why?

Comment: you can try `when...then...` to simplify your codes, `$.when($.ajax(url1) ).then($.ajax(url2))`

Comment: Could you maybe add a little more code? All you have there is three nested AJAX calls and I suspect the problem is not in the `$.ajax(...)` itself.

Comment: Why is it a problem that the rows are added to your datatable? Did you mean to write that they're _not_ added?

Answer (score 0):

Be course your 3th code gets executed in "success".

This only executes when "GetDetailsForLocationFromDB" has XMLHttpRequest.readyState = 4 AND XMLHttpRequest.status = 200.

So only when ALL data is fetched it gives all data and adds all rows at once.

So "all the rows are added to my dataTable when all data is completed" in your question is unavoidable if you do it this way. This is not an error, it works as designed.

If you want a "row by row" update you will have make a separate call for each row (using $.each in "GetLocationsForDevice").

Using this will slow things down though, be warned.